# std::vector inserting std::pair

Tags: c++, templates, stl, stdvector, std-pair

I am having trouble trying to insert a `std::pair` in the `std::vector`,  with this code:

```
template <class R>
class AVectorContainner
{
public:
  AVectorContainner()
       {
         mVector= new std::vector<entry>;
       }
  typedef std::pair<int ,R *> entry;

  void insert(R* aPointer, int aID)
  {
     entry aEntry;
     aEntry=std::make_pair(aID,aPointer );
     mVector->push_back(aEntry);

  }
private: 
  std::vector<entry> * mVector;
}
```

This is the part of the main file, that I declare a pointer of a class and then I used it in the initialization of the template class.

In the main.cpp:

```
    int main()
    {
        SomeType * aTipe= new SomeType;
        int aID=1;
        AVectorContainer<SomeType> * aContainer= new AVectorContainer;
        aContainer->insert(aTipe,aId);//error line
delete aTipe;
delete aContainer;
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiler Output:

```
error: non-static reference member 'const int& std::pair<const int&, SomeType *>::first', can't use default assignment operator

error: value-initialization of reference type 'const int&'
```

Comment: There is way too much `new` in this code.

Comment: ... and not a copy-ctor or assignment operator to be seen. ugh.

Comment: Did you forget to add a semicolon ; after your class declaration or is that just a typo in this post?

Comment: So, Ricardo, did you come from Java or C#?

Comment: The code is just for this post

Comment: @Yakk you shouldn't fix the OP's typos unless the OP fixes them himself.

Comment: @Rapptz I assumed "error occurs on this line" was true.  So I fixed typos prior to that line that would cause build breaks.

Comment: @Ricardo_arg -1 Show the real code, otherwise there'll be too much guessing going on.

Comment: @Rapptz you shouldn't introduce typos into someone elses code either.

Comment: @Yakk I didn't delete or add anything, just fixed spacing.

Comment: And there's one more typo that y'all missed :)

Comment: @Yakk Look at my revision, the extraneous brace was already there, I just put it in a code block.

Comment: [The short version](http://ideone.com/Jw6c23) would seem a wee bit less prone to error, though  I'm still not fond of that pointer.

Comment: Just my pet peeve but don't dynamically allocate a vector. There is rarely a reason to do so.

Comment: Congratulations! You have created a new programming language: **Java++**

Comment: here is a similar post: stackoverflow.com/questions/634662/…, this one is facing the same problem. one of the comment to that question was this: blog.copton.net/archives/2007/10/13/stdvector/index.html. The code doesnt compile, so fixit filling with semicolons and other isses doesnt seemt to improve the quality of the question, the compiler again is ringing with the same output, sorry but those anwser doesnt respond the question.

Comment: http://sscce.org -- if you cannot provide a simple, self contained, compiling-until-the-error example, the only way we can figure out your problem is by reading your mind.  This is not a mind reading website.  Provide code that *actually demonstrates the error*.

Comment: @Ricardo_arg the code you edited into my answer below, and the code you have above, are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original poster failed to actually post the code that was causing the problem.

He has since edited my post with the correct code that demonstrates the problem.  The code that demonstrates the problem follows:

```
template <class R, typename B=int>
class AVectorContainer
{
public:
  AVectorContainer() {}
  typedef R* ptr_Type;
  typedef const B & const_ref_Type;
  typedef std::pair<const_ref_Type ,ptr_Type> entry;


  void insert(ptr_Type aPointer, const_ref_Type aID) {
     entry aEntry=std::make_pair(aID,aPointer);
     mVector.push_back(aEntry);
  }
private:
  std::vector<entry> mVector;
};

class SomeType
{
public:
  SomeType(){ x=5; }
  ~SomeType(){ }
  int x;
};

int main()
{
  SomeType * aTipe= new SomeType;
  int aID=1;
  AVectorContainer<SomeType> aContainer;
  aContainer.insert(aTipe,aID);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:88: error: non-static reference member 'const int& std::pair<const int&, SomeType*>::first', can't use default assignment operator
```

The flaw is in these lines:

```
  typedef R* ptr_Type;
  typedef const B & const_ref_Type;
  typedef std::pair<const_ref_Type ,ptr_Type> entry;
  std::vector<entry> mVector;
```

Here, the original poster attempts to make a `vector` of `pair`s that contain a constant reference, and then does this:

```
entry aEntry;
aEntry=std::make_pair(aID,aPointer )
```

this attempts to assign one pair to another.  But `const&` variables cannot be assigned to another -- they can be constructed (initialized) from another `const&`, but not assigned.

An easy fix is:

```
entry aEntry=std::make_pair(aID,aPointer )
```

so that we are not constructing `aEntry` from another `entry`, instead of default constructing `aEntry` (which is also illegal: `const&` must be initialized), then assigning to it.

Comment: True, I didn't pay much attention to the actual code. I was too busy `SnD'ing` the typos!

Comment: seriously?? this is a solution?? just checking the types and adding some class that was just writting for showing proposing?.

Comment: @Ricardo_arg it wasn't much of a question.  Your code was full of typos -- TheOtherGuy fixed that.  I noticed you also had a pile of unnecessary `new`s: rather than editing TheOtherGuy's answer to remove them, I tossed it out here.  If ThatOtherGuy improved his answer, I'd just delete mine.

Comment: here is a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634662/non-static-const-member-cant-use-default-assignment-operator, this one is facing the same problem. one of the comment to that question was this: http://blog.copton.net/archives/2007/10/13/stdvector/index.html. The code doesnt compile, so fixit filling with semicolons and other isses doesnt seemt to improve the quality of the question, the compiler again is ringing with the same output, sorry but those anwser doesnt respond the question.

Comment: The code I wrote compiles.  I even link to a live example.  If yours does not, maybe your compiler us broken, or maybe your code is different than mine.  @ricardo_arg

Answer (score 2):

Fixed all typos, compare the two ... he did like 100 in 20 lines!

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <class R>
class AVectorContainer
{
public:
  AVectorContainer()
       {
         mVector= new std::vector<entry>;
       }
  typedef std::pair<int ,R *> entry;

  void insert(R* aPointer, int aID)
  {
     entry aEntry;
     aEntry=std::make_pair(aID,aPointer );
     mVector->push_back(aEntry);

  }
private: 
  std::vector<entry> * mVector;
};

class SomeType
{
public:
    SomeType(){ x=5; }
    ~SomeType(){ }
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    SomeType * aTipe= new SomeType;
    int aID=1;
    AVectorContainer<SomeType> * aContainer= new AVectorContainer<SomeType>;
    aContainer->insert(aTipe,aID);//error line
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After fixing all the typo's (`Containner`, `aId`, missing `;` etc.) the code compiles just fine.