# c++ sorting custom objects in vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Many topics on stackoverflow have tackled this subject, but I can't manage to get it right for my example. 
I have a class Event with the time that the event takes place.
I want to sort these objects in a vector according to that time.

I first started implementing the operator<, but then the compiler gave the following error:

> Error 1   error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Event'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    3009    1   sorting

So then I added the operator=

Below is the code I have used:

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

using namespace std;

class Event{
public:
     const double time;
     Event(double);
     bool operator<(const Event&);
     bool operator=(const Event&);
};

Event::Event(double time) :
time(time){

}

bool Event::operator<(const Event& rhs)
{
    return this->time < rhs.time;
}

bool Event::operator=(const Event& rhs)
{
    return this->time == rhs.time;
}

int main() {
    vector<Event> vector;
    Event e1 = Event(10);
    Event e2 = Event(5);
    Event e3 = Event(7);
    vector.push_back(e1);
    vector.push_back(e2);
    vector.push_back(e3);
    sort(vector.begin(), vector.end());
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug, I notice that my objects aren't sorted at all.
They are in the order I added them. 
Below is an excerpt of the 'vector' variable:

```
[0] {time=10.000000000000000 }  Event
[1] {time=5.0000000000000000 }  Event
[2] {time=7.0000000000000000 }  Event
```

**I have the following questions:**

1. Why aren't my events sorted in the vector when I call sort?
2. Why does sort need operator= ?

Comment: `operator=` is the assignment operator. Perhaps you wanted `operator==`.

Comment: Your argument naming in the operator functions are misleading, as the argument is actually the *right* hand side of the expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-static const member, can't use default assignment operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634662/non-static-const-member-cant-use-default-assignment-operator)

Comment: Don't make const members in classes, make const classes instead.

Comment: @NeilKirk : or just make it private, with a public getter.

Comment: @joachim-pileborg indeed, I have changed it!

Comment: also in operator=(const Event& lhs) you use rhs inside the method instead of lhs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that objects of your class `Event` cannot be assigned because of `const double time` member. Since the member is `const` it cannot be modified, so you cannot use `sort` on a container with `Event` objects, because sorting requires assignment.

Either remove `const` or rethink what you try to do. BTW you are confusing assignment operator (`operator=`, this is what `sort` requires`) with equality operator (`operator==`).

Answer (score 2):

To reorder the objects inside the vector the object has to be copyable (or moveable). You have to define an operator= (which is an assignment) that is of the form:

```
Event& operator=(const Event& other) 
{
    if(&other != this) { this->time = other.time; }
    return *this;
}
```

So your implementation of operator= is wrong. You are comparing the two objects but this is not what operator= (assignment!) is supposed to do. It has to assign one object (its content) to another object and return a reference to the object assigned to. 
Keep in mind that you should provide a copy constructor as well if you implement an assignment operator.

Comment: The class cannot be copied/assigned due to a const non-static member.

Comment: I did not recognize the const. I think without removing the constness of time there will be no way for doing an inplace sort.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct implementation of the custom assignment operator for the question:

```
Event& Event::operator=(const Event& other) 
{
    if(&other != this) {
        // As time is const, we modify it through a secondary reference
        // you can say it cheating with the compiler
        double &rTime = (double&) this->time;
        rTime = other.time;      // this modifies this->time variable
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Also, change the declaration of the assignment operator as well:

```
class Event{
public:
     Event& operator=(const Event&);
     // other declarations...
};
```