# c++ base class invokes a deleted or inaccessible function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, deleted-functions

I have a `player` variable which contains a vector of `Resource` class which derived from `Name` and `ID` class.

Problem lies when I'm compiling the code and the following errors appear during compilation.

```
resources.h(27): note: 'Resources &Resources::operator =(const Resources &)': function was implicitly deleted because a base class invokes a deleted or inaccessible function  'IdClass &IdClass::operator =(const IdClass &)'

idclass.h(11): note: 'IdClass &IdClass::operator =(const IdClass &)': function was implicitly deleted because 'IdClass' has a data member 'IdClass::id' of const-qualified non-class type

idclass.h(4): note: see declaration of 'IdClass::id'
```

Basically what I did in `Resources.cpp` is, I had a function that initializes the Resources of the player's vector. I was weirded out by this error because I did not I looked around in StackOverflow for some answers but I haven't seen some helpful answers. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966698/error-use-of-deleted-function) came close but I'm not sure if changing the const into a non const value is what I need.

Here's the code.

in Resources.h

```
#include "NameClass.h"
#include "IdClass.h"
#include "settings.h"
class PlayerClass;
class Resources : public NameClass, public IdClass
{
public:
    /*Sets the name and id*/
    Resources(string n, const short identifier):NameClass(n), IdClass(identifier){}
    static void InitializeResourceContainer(PlayerClass& player){
       // playerInv is a struct
       // rssContainer is a vector<Resources>
       // name_x and id_x comes from settings.h which is #defined
       player.playerInv.rssContainer.push_back(Resources(name_Stone, id_Stone));
       player.playerInv.rssContainer.push_back(Resources(name_Wood, id_Wood));
       player.playerInv.rssContainer.push_back(Resources(name_Plastic, id_Plastic));
       player.playerInv.rssContainer.push_back(Resources(name_Thatch, id_Thatch));
       player.playerInv.rssContainer.push_back(Resources(name_Fabric, id_Fabric)); // this is line 27

       // plus a lot of resources
    }
}
```

in IdClass.h

```
class IdClass
{
    const short id;// line 4
public:
    /*Sets the id*/
    IdClass(const short idToSet);
    /*returns the id*/
    short GetId() const;
}; // line 11
```

in IdClass.cpp

```
#include "IdClass.h"

/*Sets the id*/
IdClass::IdClass(const short idToSet) : id(idToSet)
{
}

/*returns the id*/
short IdClass::GetId() const { return id; }
```

This is a small piece of the code I'm working on. If you guys need more explanation or code, I can give some in the comments below.

---

Edit 1:
Looks like I forgot to place the error code after the output. Also I'm using Visual Studio 2017

```
Error C2280 'Resources &Resources::operator =(const Resources &)': attempting to reference a deleted function f:\visual studio\2017\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xutility  2310
```

Changing the variable from `const short` to `short` in IdClass.h would create a linker error in one of my classes.

```
Error LNK1120   1 unresolved externals  
Error LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > FileManager::playerName" (?playerName@FileManager@@0V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)    ArchizzleGame   C:\Users\CraftedGaming\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ArchizzleGame\ArchizzleGame\FileManager.obj    1
```

So obviously the two threads that two commenters linked weren't that helpful.

> What I aim to do is to get the id value from Resources.h to IdClass.h.

Comment: I can only see 'notes', not errors. Does it build an executable, or are there errors that you're not showing? The note is basically saying 'can't make a default assignment operator, because of the const member'.

Comment: you want to know how to copy an object when it has `const` members?

Comment: read the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634662/non-static-const-member-cant-use-default-assignment-operator  It explains why you cannot use '=' on objects that have const members .  If the project builds correctly, and you do not assign 2 objects of type resources, you should be OK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-static const member, can't use default assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634662/non-static-const-member-cant-use-default-assignment-operator)

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved your first problem by changing const short to short.  This was your last compilation error , so you moved to the linking stage. This exposed your second (unrelated!) error, a static string playerName in class FileManager which has a declaration , but no definition.

In c++ it is not enough to "declare" a static such as

```
class A
{
 static int a;
}
```

you also need to "define" it, or give it a body by adding the following line in some .cpp file ( not .h as it may get re-defined multiple times )

```
int A::a = 0;
```

However, I'm not sure you really want playerName to be a static member in class FileManager. This would mean many file managers would all share the same player name.

Answer (score 1):

Your IdClass class is not copyable/movable because of const member

```
  const short id;
```

As the result your Resources class becomes not copyable/moveable, but it is needed by std::vector.

Remove const from `short id` to make it compiles.