# C++ class constructor error: attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, class, constructor, syntax-error

This is my code which produces an error (the real cause/remedy for the error is in P.S.2, but I'm still asking for a reason):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class V2 {
public:
    long double x, y;
    V2(long double xx = 0, long double yy = 0);
    friend V2 operator+(const V2 &v1, const V2 &v2);
    friend V2 operator-(const V2 &v1, const V2 &v2);
    friend V2 operator*(const long double &r, const V2 &v);
    friend V2 operator*(const V2 &v, const long double &r);
    friend V2 operator/(const V2 &v, const long double &r);
};

V2::V2(long double X, long double Y) { x = X; y = Y; }

V2 operator+(const V2 &v1, const V2 &v2) { return V2(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y); }

V2 operator-(const V2 &v1, const V2 &v2) { return V2(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y); }

V2 operator*(const long double &r, const V2 &v) { return V2(r*v.x, r*v.y); }

V2 operator*(const V2 &v, const long double &r) { return V2(r*v.x, r*v.y); }

V2 operator/(const V2 &v, const long double &r) { return V2(v.x / r, v.y / r); }

long double Dot(const V2 &v1, const V2 &v2) { return v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y; }

long double Cross(const V2 &v1, const V2 &v2) { return v1.x*v2.y - v1.y*v2.x; }

long double DistanceSqr(const V2 &v1, const V2 &v2) { return Dot(v1 - v2, v1 - v2); }

long double Distance(const V2 &v1, const V2 &v2) { return sqrt(Dot(v1 - v2, v1 - v2)); }

class Face {
public:
    unsigned int v1, v2, v3;
    Face(int vv1 = 0, int vv2 = 0, int vv3 = 0);
};

Face::Face(int vv1, int vv2, int vv3) {
    v1 = vv1; v2 = vv2; v3 = vv3;
}

class LineSegment {
public:
    unsigned int v1, v2;
    LineSegment(int seg1 = 0, int seg2 = 0);
};

LineSegment::LineSegment(int seg1, int seg2) {
    v1 = seg1; v2 = seg2;
}

class Boundary2D {
private:
    long double threshold = 1e-7;
    unsigned int i, j;
public:
    vector<V2> p;
    vector<LineSegment> s;
    Boundary2D(vector<V2> po = {}, vector<LineSegment> seg = {});
};

Boundary2D::Boundary2D(vector<V2> po, vector<LineSegment> seg) {
    p = po; s = seg;
}

class Interior2D {
private:
    const long double threshold = 1e-7;
    unsigned int i, j;
public:
    vector<V2> p;
    vector<Face> f;
    Interior2D(vector<V2> po = {}, vector<Face> fa = {});
};

Interior2D::Interior2D(vector<V2> po, vector<Face> fa) {
    p = po; f = fa;
}

class Domain2D {
public:
    Boundary2D Boundary;
    Interior2D Interior;
    Domain2D(Boundary2D bnd = {}, Interior2D itr = {});
};

Domain2D::Domain2D(Boundary2D bnd, Interior2D itr) {
    Boundary = bnd; Interior = itr;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

the error points to inside of the Domain2D constructor "Interior = itr" ("=" is marked red) and it says: `function "Interior2D::operator=(const Interior2D &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function` and `'Interior2D &Interior2D::operator =(const Interior2D &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`. I have no clue what this is about, I thought it's just a standard constructor in case I would need to define a new `Domain2D` like this: `Domain2D d = Domain2D(some_bndry, some_interior)` instead of `d.Boundary = ...`, `d.Interior = ...` which is somewhat lengthy. What's the big deal with that Domain2D constructor, why does it raise that error?

P.S.: I found out that after commenting `private:` section of `Interior2D` class, the error vanishes. However there is the very same section in `Boundary2D` class and that does not produce an error. Moreover, I need those variables (`i`, `j`, `threshold`) to define some functions inside class (like adding a point, forming a segment or a triangle etc.). So it really boils down to: why having a private: `i`, `j`, `threshold` variables in class causes the class constructor to raise the error?

P.S.2: I found out that making `threshold` a regular long double variable (without `const`), the error vanishes. If this is the only issue, the question is: why? The `threshold` variable really acts like a constant that helps to tell if two doubles are "equal" or not and I certainly don't want it to change, it is a constant. Why aren't we allowed to make it constant? I've heard that it is better to make a variable constant if it remains constant. What does the constantness of a private variable have to do with some strange 'deleted function' error?

Comment: Try to make your constant `static constexpr long double threshold = 1e-7;` and review if you really need to pass vectors by copy and you don't need only const references, e.g. `Interior2D(const vector<V2>& po = {}, const vector<Face>& fa = {});`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, both things work. However, that still does not explain why just const long double raises the error.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634662/non-static-const-member-cant-use-default-assignment-operator).